# .npmrc file in project directory and in user directory

Tags: npm, .npmrc

i work on several projects, for most of them i need the same `.npmrc`  file, but for one of them i need different `.npmrc`file.
i configure `.npmrc` in my user folder ('C:/Useres/me/.npmrc')
and all the projects work fine,
in the one project i configure the `.npmrc` local in the project directory,
but it wont work, because it still looking into `.npmrc` that i have in my user directory..
how can i configure the one project to use `.npmrc` locally ?
it's suppose to be the default behavior but it wont work and that's what i get in the one project with the local `.npmrc`:

```
npm ERR! code E401
npm ERR! Incorrect or missing password.
npm ERR! If you were trying to login, change your password, create an
npm ERR! authentication token or enable two-factor authentication then
npm ERR! that means you likely typed your password in incorrectly.
npm ERR! Please try again, or recover your password at:
```

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

i did a work around by explictly mention:
`npm ci --userconfig=.\.npmrc`